# I am trying to reduce the width of my container border in flutter, the last I can go is "width:1” in flutter

Tags: flutter, containers, width, border, reduce

```
    Container(
                decoration:BoxDecoration(
 color:Colors.white,
 border:Border.all(width:1.0),// want to reduce the width to less than 1.
 color: Colors.white,
```

borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(20.0),

Comment: I realized I added the color property to the **box decoration **()and also added the  color property to the Border.all(). Hence it seemed like the reduction in width in Border.all(),wasn't having any effect when you reduce the value of the width. To fix this I just removed the color property in BoxDecoration (), and reduced the width as @MohammedAli requested. Thank you  all.

Answer (score 3):

you can use double value like below

```
         Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width:0.5), // 0.1 to 0.9
              color: Colors.yellow,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
```